# How can I triple boot MacOS Catalina , Ubuntu 18.04, and Windows 10

Tags: macos, windows, partition, startup, efi

I currently use the mid-2014 MacBook Pro. 
I have read the similar questions asked but as I don't have much technical knowledge I thought I should create a new question.

***Device History***

- I had installed Ubuntu along with macOS
- I recently tried to create another partition and install Windows 10
- Installation was successful but the problem was with boot entries
- I wasn't able to boot into macOS but was able to boot into Windows and Ubuntu.
- Then created [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375289/how-to-resolve-messed-up-gpt-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-from-ubuntu) to resolve the issue.
- I have backed up data from ubuntu and deleted the Windows and Ubuntu partition
- But I am not sure whether I can directly proceed to installations again as I had previous installations that might have done some changes to EFI etc.

**My `diskutil list` output is:**

```
DEREK:~ TheSwapnil$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOSX - Data           105.8 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 80.7 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume MacOSX                  10.6 GB    disk1s5
```

> Please guide me for the step-by-step installation without using
>   Bootcamp.
>
> I have .iso files of Ubuntu and bootable USB of Windows10 ready with me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

***These instructions are for the latest Intel Macs which boot macOS from an APFS volume and EFI boot both Windows and Ubuntu.***

## If you need to install Ubuntu on a Mac with an internal PCIe-based SSD and/or T2 chip, then you should read [japhwil's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127375/install-ubuntu-18-04-on-mac-mini-2018/1245535#1245535).

> Note the following:

> - If your wireless mouse or keyboard will not work during the installation process, then I assume you have a wired replacement you can temporarily use.

> - Apple introduced the T2 Security Chip and Secure Boot starting with certain Macs in 2018. If your Mac includes the Apple T2 Security Chip, then you may have to modify the security settings in order to use the procedures given below. See the Apple website [About Secure Boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330) for more information.

> - User [therobyouknow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4018/therobyouknow) has pointed out with the MacBook Pro Touch (15-inch, Late 2016), `/dev/sda` needs to be replaced by `/dev/nvme0n1p` in the instructions below.

### Removing Boot Files from Previous Windows or Ubuntu Installation

If you removed a previous version of Windows or Ubuntu, then you may have files remaining in the EFI partition (`disk0s1`). The commands given below will remove these files.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
rm -r boot ubuntu windows
cd ~
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

> Note: If the `boot` `ubuntu` or `windows` directory (folder) does not exist, then expect to get an `No such file or directory` error message.

### Installing Windows without Using the Boot Camp Assistant.

> Note: If you can use the Boot Camp Assistant application to install Windows, I would suggest you do so. These instructions are mainly for those who have a special configuration which prohibits the use of the Boot Camp Assistant application to install Windows.

1. Use the Disk Utility application to erase a 16 GB or larger flash drive. Choose the `ExFAT` format and the `Master Boot Record` scheme.
2. Mount the Windows ISO file, the copy the files to the flash drive. The current Windows 10 ISO can be downloaded from the Microsoft website [Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).
3. Copy the Windows Support Software *designed for your Mac* to the flash drive. The Windows Support Software can be downloaded by using the Boot Camp Assistant application. Select `Action->Download Window Support Software` from menu bar.

   Below is the contents of Windows installation flash drive as viewed in the Finder application. The `AutoUnattend.xml` file and both the `$WinPEDriver$` and `BootCamp` folders came from the Windows Support Software downloaded from Apple for an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013). The remaining files and folders were from the `Win10_1909_English_x64.iso` file downloaded from Microsoft.

   [image]
4. Create free space to be used by Windows. In this example, 400 GB will be reserved for Windows on a 1.1 TB drive. Before allocating the free space, the output from the command `diskutil list disk0` is shown below.

   ```
   /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.1 TB     disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.1 TB     disk0s2
   ```

   To make 300 GB of free space available, the command shown below was used.

   ```
   sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 700G
   ```

   The new output from the command `diskutil list disk0` is shown below. Notice, the 300 GB block of free space created directly below `disk0s2` is not shown.

   ```
   /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.1 TB     disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         700.0 GB   disk0s2
   ```
5. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Choose the `EFI Boot` label below the flash drive icon.
6. When the image below appears, press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination.
   [image]
   The Command Prompt window shown below should appear.
   [image]
7. Enter the following command to create the Windows partitions. There commands are based on the instructions found at the Microsoft website [UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions).

   ```
   diskpart
   select disk 0
   create partition msr size=16
   create partition primary 
   shrink desired=800
   format quick fs=ntfs label=BOOTCAMP
   assign letter=w
   create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
   format quick fs=ntfs label=Recovery
   gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001
   list partition
   exit
   ```

   The output from the `list partition` command for this example is given below.

   ```
     Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
     -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
     Partition 1    System             200 MB    20 KB
     Partition 2    Unknown            651 GB   200 MB
     Partition 3    Reserved            16 MB   652 GB
     Partition 4    Primary            371 GB   652 GB
   * Partition 5    Recovery           800 MB  1023 GB
   ```

   Enter the command `exit` to close the Command Prompt window.
8. Proceed and finish the installation of Windows.

   > Note: If the Mac boots back to macOS before the installation of Windows completes, open the Startup Disk pane of the System Preferences application. After unlocking, highlight the icon labeled Windows and then click on the `Restart` button. The installation of Windows should proceed.
9. If after Windows finishes installing, the Windows Support Software does not automatically starting installing, run the `Setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder on the flash drive.

### Installing Ubuntu

1. Download the latest Ubuntu installation ISO file from the [Ubuntu Home Page](https://ubuntu.com/#download). The file download and used in this answer was named `ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`.
2. Create free space to install Ubuntu. In this example, 300 GB of space will be reserved for Ubuntu. The output from `diskutil list disk0` after install Windows is shown below.

   ```
   /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.1 TB     disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         700.0 GB   disk0s2
      3:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s3
      4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                398.4 GB   disk0s4
      5:           Windows Recovery                         838.9 MB   disk0s5
   ```

   > Note: In this example, the EFI partition (`disk0s1`) is 209.7 MB. Remember the size of the EFI partition on your drive. You will need this value in a later step.

   The command given below will shrink the APFS by 300 GB.

   > Note: To be compatible with macOS, the entries in the Guid partition table (GPT) should occur in ascending order. To help insure this happens, dummy partitions need to be created when reserving the free space. Since the Ubuntu installer will be creating two new partitions, the command given below will create two dummy partitions.

   ```
   sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 400G exfat DUMMY1 200M exfat DUMMY2 200M
   ```

   The dummy partition can arbitrary in size, since the partitions will be deleted later. The output from the command `diskutil list disk0`, after entering the above command, is given below.

   ```
   /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.1 TB     disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         400.0 GB   disk0s2
      3:       Microsoft Basic Data DUMMY1                  199.2 MB   disk0s8
      4:       Microsoft Basic Data DUMMY2                  199.2 MB   disk0s9
      5:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s3
      6:       Microsoft Basic Data                         398.4 GB   disk0s4
      7:           Windows Recovery                         838.9 MB   disk0s5
   ```
3. Use [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to create a bootable Ubuntu flash drive installer, then boot from this flash drive. A tutorial can be found at the Ubuntu website [Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0).
4. When the menu below appears, select `Try Ubuntu without installing`.

   [image]
5. When the Ubuntu desktop appears, press the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key combination to open a terminal window.
6. Temporarily rename the folders containing the Windows EFI boot files. This is done so certain files will not be overwritten when Ubuntu installs. Also, this will prevent Windows being added to the GRUB boot menu. Enter the following commands to rename the folders

   ```
   sudo -i
   mkdir efi
   mount /dev/sda1 efi
   mv efi/EFI efi/EFI.win
   umount efi
   rmdir efi
   exit
   ```
7. Enter the command `exit` to close the terminal window, then double click on the icon labeled `Install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` shown on the desktop. Proceed with install Ubuntu.
8. When the screen shown below appears, select "Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats", as shown below.

   [image]
9. When the screen shown below appears, select "Something else", as shown below.

   [image]
10. Delete the dummy partitions. Since the output from `diskutil list disk0` showed the third and fourth partitions to be the dummies, the window below will identify these dummy partitions as devices `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4`. Highlight device `/dev/sda3`, then click on the `-` button to delete. Repeat for the `/dev/sda4`.

    [image]
11. Highlight the 300 GB of free space, as shown below, then click on the `+` button to add a new partition.

    [image]

    In the popup window, select a size and a use as of `EFI System Partition`, as shown below. Here, `210` MB was used since the size of the original EFI partition was 209.7 MB. You should enter a value equal to the size of the original EFI partition on your drive rounded up to the nearest MB. Next, click on the `OK` button.

    [image]
12. Highlight the remaining free space, as shown below, then click on the `+` button to add new partition.

    [image]

    In the popup window, select a mount point of `/`, as shown below. Let use as default to `Ext4 journaling file system` and **do not** change the size. Next, click on the `OK` button.

    [image]
13. Since all the new partitions have been created, click on the `Install Now` button. When the screen show below appears, click on the `Continue` button. Proceed and install Ubuntu.

    [image]
14. When Ubuntu finishes installing, the Mac will need to be restarted. If asked to remove the installation medium, then do so. When the Mac restarts, immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appears. Next, hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while selecting the `EFI Boot` label under the internal drive icon. The Mac should boot Ubuntu.
15. From the Ubuntu desktop, press the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key combination to open a terminal window. Enter the following commands to move the Ubuntu EFI boot files to the new EFI partition and restore the Windows boot folder names.

    ```
    sudo -i
    mkdir efi
    mount /dev/sda3 efi
    mv /boot/efi/EFI efi
    mv /boot/efi/EFI.win /boot/efi/EFI
    umount efi
    rmdir efi
    ```
16. Use the following command to label `sda3` with `EFI2`.

    ```
    fatlabel /dev/sda3 EFI2
    ```

    Use the following command to get the UUID value for the old (`sda1`) and new (`sda3`) partitions (to be used in the next step).

    ```
    blkid /dev/sda1 /dev/sda3
    ```

    From the output, the UUID value for `sda1` and `sda3` was determined to be `02E4-255E` and `2BCF-0C4E`, respectively. In your case, the UUID values themselves will be specific to your machine. The given UUID values are as an example and will likely be different in your case, as would be expected. The next step shows what to do with the UUID values.
17. Change the UUID in the `/etc/fstab` file. Use the command `nano /etc/fstab` or some other command to open the `/etc/fstab` file in an editor. Replace the UUID for `sda1` with the UUID for `sda3`. For this example, this would mean to replacing `02E4-255E` with `2BCF-0C4E`. Save the change and close the editor.
18. Make sure the drive is not using hybrid partitioning. This can be accomplished by entering the command given below.

    ```
    gdisk /dev/sda
    ```

    This command is interactive. The interactive commands you will need to enter when prompted by `gdisk` are given below.

    ```
    x
    n
    w
    y
    ```
19. Finally, enter the command `exit` twice to close the terminal window. Restart the Mac.

### Adding an Ubuntu Icon and Label to the Startup Manager Menu (Optional)

1. Boot back to macOS.
2. Download a collection of icons from the sourceforge web
   site [Mac icns](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/). Use the Finder application to open the
   downloaded file `mac-icns.dmg`.
3. Open a Terminal application window and enter the command given below to mount the EFI partition (`/dev/disk0s3`) containing the Ubuntu boot files.

   ```
   sudo diskutil mount disk0s3
   ```

   Under Ubuntu, this is the `/dev/sda3` partition. The volume stored in this partition was given the volume label `EFI2` during one of the previous Ubuntu installation steps.
4. Enter the command below to copy the Ubuntu icon file `os_ubuntu.icns` to the `EFI2` volume.

   ```
   cp /Volumes/mac-icns/OSX10.11.6/os_ubuntu.icns /Volumes/EFI2/.VolumeIcon.icns
   ```

   This will add the following Ubuntu icon to the Startup Menu.

   [image]

   > Note: When finished, you can use the Finder application to eject the `mac-icns` volume.
5. Use the command shown below to change the label that will be shown below the Ubuntu icon on the Startup Manager menu.

   ```
   bless --folder /Volumes/EFI2/EFI/BOOT --label "Ubuntu"
   ```
6. Use the Finder application or enter the command below to unmount
   the EFI System partition labeled `EFI2`.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk0s3
   ```

### References

[About Secure Boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330)
[About the Apple T2 Security Chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862)
[Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)
[UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions)
[Ubuntu Home Page](https://ubuntu.com)
[Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)
[Etcher Home Page](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)
[How to move EFI and boot partitions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111845/how-to-move-efi-and-boot-partitions)
[Installing Ubuntu on Mac with macOS and Windows already installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257166/installing-ubuntu-on-mac-with-macos-and-windows-already-installed)
[Dual-Booting OS X or macOS with Linux without rEFInd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831161/dual-booting-os-x-or-macos-with-linux-without-refind)
[Mac icons](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/)

Comment: Great write-up!   I am having one area where I'm stumbling a bit, on step #6 in the Ubuntu setup, it is not allowing me to mount the EFI device. It says the device is either mounted (it isn't) or in use.  Any pointers you can give here?

Comment: I would need you to post the output from the command `blkid`. You could try to post this output as a comment. Or, you could create a question where you refer to this question and add the output there.

Comment: I have a few questions: In the _Installing Ubuntu_ section, step #2, why are 2 DUMMY partitions being created when both are being deleted in step #10 ? (is this because of the ordering requirement you mentioned in step #2).

Comment: In step #15, after renaming the Window EFI folder back to how it was, my Mac will now longer boot into Windows, but can't see why this would be, if it is exactly the same as originally.

Comment: Finally from me, in Step #17 why does the UUID have to be changed if Ubuntu can already be found when doing step #14. My `/dev`s are prefixed `nvm` not `sda`. After doing all steps Ubuntu drive option missing, as well as Windows boot option not booting as mentioned in previous comment. Thank you for reading and Happy New Year!

Comment: The software used in step 10 does not necessarily keep the GPT entries in ascending order. The instructions attempt to accomplish this through the use of temporary dummy partitions. The comment about Windows not booting in step 15 is to vague for me to provide a good answer. Perhaps, the [BCD needs to be rebuilt](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508) by using `bootrec`. Step 17 is in response to the move of Ubuntu boot files done in step 15, which occurs after booting Ubuntu in step 14.

Comment: If you find solutions to problems with respect to this answer, then I hope you will either update this answer or post your own answer. You can copy from my answer if you wish. (This includes the entire answer, if you want, as a starting point.) Also, users have posted a new question about an answer to a existing question. You may choose to do this if you can not fully explain your problem through a comment.

Comment: @therobyouknow: Happy New Year to you also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102746/discussion-between-david-anderson-and-therobyouknow).

Comment: Yes +1 @DavidAnderson happy to chat - I've added my sub-question as a separate question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378754/triple-boot-mac-win10-ubuntu-how-to-restore-original-copy-of-windows-efi-to-ens

Comment: In that sub-question, I've suggested a possible lead to explore: "instead of step 6 moving the Windows EFI folders to stop GRUB altering it, make a copy to restore back at end of steps, instead. My theory is that macOS bootmanager doesn't find Windows on a subsequent reboot after I did step 6, it adjusts itself to ignore it. By having the original there, it wont do that - AND - at the end we can restore the copy, overwriting what GRUB did. I haven't tried this yet."

Comment: Had great success following this guide using Ubuntu 20.04 together with the other two OS's. Have one question - is there a way to change the name of my Apple Start Up Disk (shows as "Untitled" when pressing the Option Key on start). The other two StartUp disks show as "Linux" and "Windows'. Have tried various suggestions on other forums without success.

Comment: In the end I simply re-installed Catalina on its partition, via the Recovery Option, Cmd+R (The original OS the mac shipped with was Yosemite, which was immediately upgraded, after Yosemite was re-installed via the recovery option). End result was that the StartUp Disk was renamed, without any further intervention, to Apple.

Comment: This is the best tutorial on this topic I’ve seen so far, but I still didn’t have any luck (I’m actually just trying to install Ubuntu and don’t need Windows). It’s always the same error for me: the installation works fine until „Executing 'grub-install /dev/nvme0n1' failed - This is a fatal error“. I‘m working on a 2018 Mac mini, I’ve tried the internal and external drives, with and without rEFInd and with Ubuntu versions 18, 19 and 20. I’ve used Etcher and Unetbootin for the boot sticks. I’m really getting quite desperate now and would be super grateful if you could help!

Comment: I also gave Boot Repair in Ununtu a go which also failed on me with an error and generated this report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S9sB4HgTn6/

Comment: @japhwil: AFAIK there is no driver available that can be used to install Ubuntu on the internal drive of a 2018 Mac mini. You probably should post a new question here at Ask Different or at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). I should point out that your question has already been asked. See [Install ubuntu 18.04 on mac mini 2018](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127375/install-ubuntu-18-04-on-mac-mini-2018).

Comment: Thank you @DavidAnderson! I'll have a look at the question you linked.

Comment: So I finally figured it out! What's key is to install Ubuntu without GRUB and then install rEFInd as a boot manager. I collected my findings here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1245535/1075751

Comment: @DavidAnderson for steps 15 and 16 please could the commands be separated out onto separate lines. At the moment several commands are all on one line. For step 15 I'm almost certain of where one command ends and the next starts. For step 16 it's harder to tell. Also in 16 there is mention of "get the UUID" - does one of the commands mentioned do this or is "get the UUID" and instruction for me to get it and if so where do I use it in the command? Thankyou for your help.

Comment: I've edited the text referred to in my previous comment myself and this has been approved by jaume - thank you. I'm looking forward to trying out this guide myself thank you for writing it, David Anderson!

Comment: Thanks for your tutorial, that's amazing. I have decided to make a dual boot with Linux and Windows only, however I fail at the optional part labeling the linux efi from "EFI Boot" to "Ubuntu". `bless` seems to be only an osx specific tool. Is there an equivalent command to `bless --folder /Volumes/EFI2/EFI/BOOT --label "Ubuntu"` for linux?

Comment: I do not know of Linux command to create the label files.

Answer (score 0):

David Anderson posted a very good and detailed manual.
But it looks very complicated and extensive.
This may put many people off.
Some steps can be omitted or simplified.
I've decided to make an easier instruction:

1. Install MacOS (you probably already have it).
2. Install Windows via **Bootcamp** (I saved 100G for MacOS and 400G for Windows).
3. Go into Windows and use **Disk Management** to shrink its partition (I trimmed 30G for Ubuntu)
4. Boot from Ubuntu install flash drive and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**
5. Open a **Terminal** rename EFI from Windows:

```
sudo -i
mkdir efi
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 efi
mv efi/EFI efi/EFI.win
umount efi
rmdir efi
```

6. Run the Ubuntu installation from the desktop
7. During the installation select "**Something else**".
8. Select a 30G free space and create an "**EFI System Partition**" 1M larger than nvme0n1p1 (315M)
9. Select the remaining free space and create an "**Ext4 journaling file system**" partition, specify the **Mount point** as "/".
10. Install Ubuntu.
11. After rebooting go to **Terminal** to move EFI partitions from Windows and Ubuntu:

```
sudo -i
mkdir efi
mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 efi
mv /boot/efi/EFI efi
mv /boot/efi/EFI.win /boot/efi/EFI
umount efi
rmdir efi
fatlabel /dev/nvme0n1p5 EFI2
```

12. change UUID:

```
blkid /dev/nvme0n1p1 /dev/nvme0n1p5
nano /etc/fstab
```

13. Remove any existing hybrid partitioning

```
gdisk /dev/nvme0n1
x
n
w
y
```

14. Boot into MacOS
15. Download and run mac-icns:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/
```

16. Assign icon and label to Ubuntu:

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s5
cp /Volumes/mac-icns/OSX10.11.6/os_ubuntu.icns /Volumes/EFI2/.VolumeIcon.icns
bless --folder /Volumes/EFI2/EFI/BOOT --label "Ubuntu"
diskutil unmount disk0s5
```